# Convert a HTML site into a Wiki

Tags: html, converters, mediawiki, wiki

I have a basic HTML site (No JavaScript, PHP or CSS) that I would like to turn into a Wiki. The site has over 1000 pages. I would like the converter to take the contents of each page, and place the content into a its own newly created wiki page. I also need all the links to be converted as well. I would prefer to use MediaWiki, but any wiki software would do.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: I would recommend for you to crawl the html files with php or your language of preference and push that to a database or something that you can use =)

Comment: Provided the content of the current website is in a consistent format then this shouldn't be too much trouble. Can you provide some more information on how it currently is (in terms of elements and where data is) and also let us know what you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

IIRC Reimar Bauer has written some tool to recover MoinMoin 1.9.x contents from html content on archive.org. Maybe you can slightly modify that for your purpose.

But be aware that that was made to convert html that was MADE by moin, maybe rather not arbitrary html. But if you html is simple, it might be worth trying.

Another idea (maybe needing a bit more research and coding) is to use the post url that is used by the gui editor of moin. It expects xhtml there and will try to convert that to moin wiki markup. You can also do a first try interactively by just copy&pasting your html to the gui editor of moin. But be aware that browsers do a sanitizing step (convert html to valid xhtml) that is not present if you just post (not well-formed) html to the post url.